# Debug jupyter notebook within docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VSCode to debug a jupyter notebook which runs within a docker container.
I am using `jupyter/scipy-notebook:python-3.9.7` as base image and running the following command:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "ptvsd", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "49155", "--wait", "--multiprocess", "-m", "jupyter", "lab", "--ip", "0.0.0.0"]
```

after having installed ptvsd.

The launch.json looks like the following:

```
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 49155
        },
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/notebooks",
                "remoteRoot": "/home/jovyan"
            }
        ]
```

where all the relevant code is within the notebooks folder.

After building and "upping" the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    scipy-notebook:
        ports:
            - '49154:8888'
            - '49155:49155'
        environment:
            - 'JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp'
            - 'JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes'
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ${dockerfile_src}
        image: ${registry}/${repositoryName}:${versionNumber}
```

the container is correctly waiting for me to attach a visual studio debug session (i.e. "Attaching to <container_name>"), but after I start the debug session, this stops immediately and the jupyter notebook starts normally. Further attempts to attach bring the same result.

I tried to debug a simple .py file within the notebooks folder with the very same structure, and in this case everything works just fine. Here the command:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "ptvsd", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "49155", "--wait", "main.py"]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug? Is this something with the code in the notebook? Maybe you could give the [JupyterLab Debugger](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html) a try? I know it's early days for it, but looking for feedback! To the question, you likely need to pass a port of the kernel with a debugger enabled, not of the jupyter server. I am not sure how you could get it though.

Comment: Indeed I am trying to debug code from libraries used in the Jupyter notebook. The Jupyter debugger is per se pretty good indeed, but if I got it correctly I can not set break points in arbitrary parts of the libraries. Thanks for the hint about the kernel. Probably it is more difficult thank I would have hoped for

Comment: That's correct, support for setting breakpoints at arbitrary code files is WIP: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/11566 (hopefully coming in the next version).

Comment: If you put it as answer I can accept it if you like, if not I will in general wait to see if anyone posts anything else